# Github tokens not working?

Tags: github

I created a token like described here - https://help.github.com/articles/git-over-http-using-oauth-token. This was ok.

But when I wan to use it like in documentation:

```
git clone https://mytoken@github.com/mylogin/myrepo.git
```

I get:

```
fatal: https://mytoken@github.com/mylogin/myrepo.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

I have a feeling that everything I tried from Github documentation doesn't work :( I am doing something wrong or the documentation is outdated or doesn't describe some steps that should be so common that I should already know? :)

I am using private repository, not public.

Comment: Did you double check if you did any case (lowercase or upercase) mistake in your username or git repo name?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. If I remove the token, it ask for my username and passwords and this is working. But I need to automate it (and I don't want to store the plaintext password somewhere). The scopes section for the token corresponds with my repository name so I don't see anything that could be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I created the token with my repository name in scopes section instead of the word repo.

Comment: Interesting to know: So there was a mistake of sorts related to the repo name as I commented above, not just the one I had in mind. Good feedback. +1

Comment: Yes, and theirs API didn't returned an error code when I sent bad arguments so it looked ok for me. I contacted the support and they said that they will make the docs more clear and that they should return some error code but I didn't tested it since the reply, perhaps it is fixed now.